# Laravel eloquent where replace and compare

Tags: php, laravel, mysqli, eloquent

I've a `phone number` column in the `users` table. The phone numbers are in different formats:

- 123-456-7890
- (123) 456 7890

  etc...

I would like to compare by removing the extra characters and retrieve the results.

Here is the **mysql query**:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`phonenumber`, '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') = '1234567890'
```

**How can do I this in the Laravel Eloquent?**

I know the best option would be to force the formatting on the DB column. I'm wondering if we can do this with Laravel Eloquent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not going to be database-agnostic, but:

```
$query->whereRaw('REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`phonenumber`, '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') = ?', [$phoneNumber]);
```

See **Raw Methods** at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

---

The better approach would be to remove these characters before inserting the numbers into the database.